# Javascript - Handle promises within catch block

Tags: javascript, promise

I am having chained promises handled by one catch block.

If one of the promises rejects, I want to do the clean up in the catch block depending on which step failed.

However, the cleanup itself also returns a Promise which needs to fulfill before I can finally reject the function.

The issue is:
What if my cleanup promise does not resolve? Wouldn‘t this cause a loop of .then & .catch? How can I make sure that my cleanup executes before ending the function?

Example:

```
return promise1()
.then(() => promise2)
.then(() => promise3)
.then(() => {
   return { result: xyz }
}
.catch((error) => {
    return cleanup()
    .then(() => {
       throw(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: There’s no loop. You should make a `cleanup` function that rejects and play around with it.

Comment: Could you just add another `.catch` to the chain on cleanup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would just use `async` / `await` syntax. This allows for simpler control of waits and resolve / reject values.

```js
const myAsyncFun = async () => {
  try {
    await promise1()
    await promise2
    await promise3
    return { result: "xyz" }
  }
  catch (error) {
    try {
      await cleanup()
    }
    catch (cleanupError) {
      // handle cleanup error
    }
    finally {
      throw error // reject with the original error
    }
  }
}
```

Original answer below...

---

Sounds like you want to use [Promise.prototype.finally()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally)

> When the promise is settled, i.e **either fulfilled or rejected**, the specified callback function is executed

```js
.catch(error => 
  cleanup()
    .catch(cleanupErr => {
      // handle cleanup error here
    })
    .finally(() => Promise.reject(error))
)
```

This will ensure that the result is a rejected promise (rejecting with `error`) whether `cleanup()` resolves or not.

---

Demo

```js
const cleanup = (fail) =>
  !fail ? Promise.resolve("cleanup good") : Promise.reject("cleanup bad")
  
const go = (failMain, failCleanup) => {
  const p = !failMain
    ? Promise.resolve("main good") 
    : Promise.reject("main bad")
  
  return p.then(() => ({ result: "xyz" }))
    .catch(error => 
      cleanup(failCleanup)
        .catch(cleanupErr => {
          // handle cleanup error here
          console.warn(cleanupErr)
        })
        .finally(() => Promise.reject(error))
    )
}

(async () => {
  console.info("No errors")
  await go(false, false).then(console.log, console.error)

  console.info("Main error only")
  await go(true, false).then(console.log, console.error)

  console.info("Main and cleanup errors")
  await go(true, true).then(console.log, console.error)
})()
```

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering what I should do if the cleanup rejects since the cleanup might be critical for the app state. Any idea on how to “ensure” or deal with it?

Comment: @ktm125 I've added some more info and a demo

Answer (score 1):

To your first question: No! Once your program is in the catch block, it has nothing to do with the promises in it, so it will not catch *cleanup()*.

To your second question: You can of course write another catch block for it and throw an error with a relevant error message (For instance "Cleanup could not be executed")

Comment: The problem is that if `cleanup()` fails, the final result will be the `cleanup` rejection value and not the original `error`

Comment: That problem can also be solved by throwing it anyways in the catch block of the 
 cleanup() function.

Answer (score 0):

You're good to go.

Your current code will await the `cleanup` function properly, because returning a promise from a chaining callback (`then`, `catch`, `finally`) makes both resolution and rejection propagate correctly.

Even if the `cleanup` function failed, it wouldn't cause any problems; the rejection would propagate to the outermost (returned) promise, and the caller code could catch it the same way as a failure from the `promise1`, `promise2` or `promise3` functions.